# Assigning to a variable in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty, template-engine

I would like to save the result of the value attribute of the `qty_hidden` input into a variable `$selectedQty` and then use it to on the dropdownbox to determine which option should be selected.

```
<input type="hidden" name="qty_hidden" value="{if $quantityDisplayed == 0 AND isset($customizedDatas.$productId.$productAttributeId)}{$customizedDatas.$productId.$productAttributeId|@count}{else}{$product.cart_quantity-$quantityDisplayed}{/if}">

<select name="qty">
<option value="1"{if $selectedQty==1}{" selected='selected'"}{/if}>1</option>
<option value="2"{if $selectedQty==2}{" selected='selected'"}{/if}>2</option>
<option value="3"{if $selectedQty==3}{" selected='selected'"}{/if}>3</option>
</select>
```

After reading the Smarty documentation, I still don't understand how to put that into a variable.

Comment: Read the section [`Smarty for programmers`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/smarty.for.programmers.tpl) in the Smarty documentation. Read about the methods first and start with [`assign()`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.assign.tpl) and [`display()`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.display.tpl). That's all you need for a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign it beforehands and use it later:

```
{$selectedQty = ""} <?php // default ?>
{if $quantityDisplayed == 0 AND isset($customizedDatas.$productId.$productAttributeId)}
   {$selectedQty = $customizedDatas.$productId.$productAttributeId|@count}
{else}
   {$selectedQty = ($product.cart_quantity-$quantityDisplayed)}
{/if}
<input type="hidden" name="qty_hidden" value="{$selectedQty}">

<select name="qty">
<option value="1"{if $selectedQty==1}{" selected='selected'"}{/if}>1</option>
<option value="2"{if $selectedQty==2}{" selected='selected'"}{/if}>2</option>
<option value="3"{if $selectedQty==3}{" selected='selected'"}{/if}>3</option>
</select>
```

Read more about [assigning variables in the docs](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.builtin.functions.tpl#language.function.shortform.assign).